# C# properties usage

Tags: c#, properties, coding-style, implementation

No, this is not another question about WHY we should use properties in C# :) I'd like to know what's the main difference between

```
private string _name;
public string Name  {
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; } 
}
```

and

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I know that with the introduction of .NET 3.0, you are able to use the latter, but I still find pieces of code that use the former.

I'm interested in knowing what are (if any) the differences between them in performance (except for the fact that I'm wasting twice the space), in the style and how the underlying implementation works.

I'd like to know what's your opinion too and which one do you use in your code.

Thank you and happy coding!

Answer (score 9):

> I know that with the introduction of .NET 3.0, you are able to use the latter

No, it's with the introduction of C# 3. You can target .NET 2 and still use automatically implemented properties. It's important to differentiate between the version of C# that you're using and the version of .NET that you're targeting.

But there's no significant difference between the two snippets you used, except that when using an automatically implemented property, no other source code has access to the field. The field is given an "unspeakable name" (one which is valid in IL but not in C#). (When you use an automatically implement property, the compiler also applies the [`[CompilerGenerated]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx) attribute to the property, too, but that's very rarely important.)

There's no performance difference in either time or memory.

Answer (score 4):

As you know, this feature is called [`Auto-Implemented Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make
>   property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required
>   in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create
>   objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following
>   example, **the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that
>   can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.**

From you

> I'm interested in knowing what are (if any) the differences between
>   them in performance (except for the fact that I'm wasting twice the
>   space), in the style and how the underlying implementation works.

In your case, there is no issue about difference and performance between them. Because you are not doing anything (any validation or etc..) while setting or retrieving the value.

As a tip, you can set a *breakpoint* in the `set/get` modifiers, but you can't set in auto property. As another one, you have to define a field (`_name` in your case) in normal property.

Comment: Ah, since that they are implemented in the same way, why are some people still using the old-way ?

Comment: @EdoardoTygerDominici I imagine because you can set breakpoints, like Soner said. Also, if the setter is private and the class is immutable you can make the underlying field `readonly`.

Comment: @EdoardoTygerDominici As I said in my answer, people might want to do some validation in setter or getter property.  For example `get
    {
        if (_name > 0)
            return someInt;
        else
            return -1;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

They both will give you the same result but you should be aware to the fact that the "manual" implementation of a property enables you to control over what is set and what is received from, which is the main idea behind properties, for example:

```
private string _name;
public string Name  {
    get { return _name; }
    set { if(_name.Length > 3) _name = value; } 
}
```

While with "auto" implemented property you're just having a *plain* degenerated property:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```